# Sinatra - Register startup and shutdown operations

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm designing a web service using Sinatra and I need to perform certain operations when the service is started and some other operations when the server is stopped.

How can I register those operations to be fully integrated with sinatra?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you need to perform your operations. Does they need to be ran for each ruby process or do they need to be ran just once for the service. I suppose it's once for all the service and in the case of the latest :

You might be tempted to run some code before your Sinatra app is starting but this is not really the behavior you might expect. I'll explain why just after. The workaround would be adding code before your sinatra class like

```
require "sinatra"
puts "Starting"

get "/" do 
  ...
end
```

You could add some code to your config.ru too btw, would have the same effect but I don't which one is uglier.

Why is this wrong ? Because when you host your web service, many web server instances will be fired and each one will execute the puts method or your "starting" code. This is correct when you want to initialize things that are local to your app instance, like a database connection but not to initialize things which are shared by all of them.

And about the code firing at its end, well you can't (or maybe you could with some really ugly workaround, but you'll end with the same issue you get with the start).

So the best way to handle on and off operations would be to wrap it within your tasks firing your service.

1. Run some rake task or ruby script that do your initalization stuff
2. Start your web server

And to stop it

1. Run a rake task or ruby script that stops the server
2. Run your rake task or ruby script that does the cleaning operations.

You can wrap those into a single rake task, by starting your app server directly from ruby, like I did there https://github.com/TactilizeTeam/photograph/blob/master/bin/photograph.

This way you can easily add some code to get ran before starting the service, still keeping it into a single task. With some plumbing, I guess you can fire multiple thin instances and then allow you to start your cluster of thin (or whatever you use) instances and have still one task to rely on.

I'd say that adding a handler to the SIGINT signal could allow you to run some code before exiting. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html for how to do that. You might want to check if Thin isn't already registering a trap for that signal, I'm not sure if this is handled in the library or in the script used to launch thin ( the "thin" executable that gets in your $PATH).

Another way to handle the exit, would be to have a watchdog process, that check if your cluster is running and could ensure the stop code is being ran if no more instances are running.

Comment: Yeah, I do need to perform it once for the whole instance (not once per process). Rake is fine but what I need is to make the process atomic meaning that 1 and 2 (run rake AND start the server, so as stop the server AND run rake) must be run always togheter, I cannot leave it to people to remember because the operation that has to be performed is vital for the safety of other services... do you have some suggestion about this? Also run the sinatra webserver from rake would just be fine.

Comment: I added some example code and explanations on how to do that :)

Comment: Thank you so much you were very kind! +1